# Bash - Renaming episode names to remove junk

Tags: bash, rename

When I am looking at episode names, often they're in the format of:

```
The.Show.Name.S06E01.lots.of.junk-often_with_chars.mkv
The.Show.Name.S06E02.lots.of.junk-often_with_chars.avi
Show.Name.S06E03.lots.of.junk-often_with_chars.mp4
```

I'd like to end up with a simple:

```
Show Name S06E01.mkv
Show Name S06E02.avi
Show Name S06E03.mp4
```

Ideas on a simple bash command or two I could run to clean up all the junk, remove the periods other than the end, allow for any three-digit file extension?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the answers to the (many, many) other questions about renaming files on this site? If you experienced a specific problem trying to apply a specific suggestion, that would be a stronger place to come from in asking a new question.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far and the (incorrect) output generated by your code